# VBA result inconsist between computers - setting .value to formula

Tags: vba, excel

I created and ran a VBA sub on my main computer, but it is not working as expected on my laptop (both use Excel 2013).

```
Set headerColumn_total = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Consensus").ListObjects("TblConsensusTotals").ListColumns.Add
colPosition = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Consensus").ListObjects("TblConsensusTotals").ListColumns.Count
colPosition = colPosition - 1
CellValue = "=SUM(TblConsensus[" & colPosition & "])"
headerColumn_total.Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = CellValue
headerColumn_total.Range.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

Explanation of code:
As you can see, the first line adds a column to the end of a 2 row table, TblConsensusTotals. Then, the number of columns is counted (subtract 1) and assigned to colPosition. CellValue is the exact text I want as the cell value, and the interior color as well of course.

On my main computer (Expected):
The topmost cell (1st row of table) in the column receives the formula, and the 2nd row cell, (.Range.Cells(2,1)), is empty. Color set is the same.

On my laptop (Observed):
Both the 1st and 2nd row cells of the column receive the formula, as if it was given to the whole range and not just Cells(1,1). However, the Color still only sets on the 1st cell, as expected.

I'm sure there is a .001 version difference in the VBA or something, but I have no clue how to look. Is there a different way I can write this to have it work on both computers?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention. Interestingly, if you set .Value = anything but a formula (say, .Value = 2) instead of having CellValue there defined as a string containing a formula, it works as expected on both the main and laptop computer, setting the Value of only the single cell. A string does the same. But once you make it a formula ('=' sign) in the string, it "breaks" and sets the value to both cells on the laptop.

Comment: based on how formulas work inside of `tables` the observed data on your laptop is the *correct* behavior.

Comment: If that is the case, how do I break it the other way? Point is, I want to change the value of a single cell in the range, not the whole range. Edit: Keep in mind there are 2 different tables, TblConsensusTotals and TblConsensus. The reason TblConsensusTotals exists is because I needed 2 Totals rows, not just 1. So I just made a 2nd table with just 2 rows of data (no header or total). So that said, why on earth is a string containing a formula sent to the range while a string that doesn't contain a formula only goes to one cell?

Comment: What about using `.Formula` instead of `.Value`?

Comment: @AndréNeves Same issue occurs

Comment: @Jeeped Seeing as to how this is in the VBA text editor, I do not understand that suggestion.

Comment: @Jeeped - No problem, I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Unfortunately, working with Excel objects from VBA just plain **sucks** sometimes and you have to come up with awful workarounds. Some from the top of my head: 1. try to flip the order of `.Value` and `.ColorIndex` lines. 2. try to write somewhere else before writing to the cell you want. 3. if it's acceptable, simply erase the duplicated value (or store it before the faulty writing and then write it back). Tips #1 and #2 might make it work all of a sudden, and #3 is a potential solution for you.

Comment: Is this a 'linked' table? Does it have a Data ► Connections ► Connection? If it does, check the connection's Fill down formulas option in the External Data Range Properties dialog box.

Comment: @AndréNeves - 1. No go, 2. and 3. no go because I set the value of the 2nd cell this same way. Was just keeping the question as simple as I could. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: @Jeeped - Not sure what a linked table is, but this table doesn't reference anything outside of the sheet (the sum is summing a column in a table directly above). No UDFs. The only macros acting are 4 to add row, add column, delete row, delete column. The add column macro is the only one also setting a value to added cells, and that's what the above code is doing.

Comment: So writing in other cells duplicates just as much, no matter in what part of your code?

Comment: @AndréNeves - Other cells in the table, yes. No matter which column, assigning the value that way in either row will cause both cells in that column to be assigned a value. Think I'm just going to make another table, splitting the table of 2 rows into 2 tables of 1. The only reason I'm using a table is because it is easy to insert a column with formatting. 2 tables for the job is clumsy, but it'll work.

Comment: Go to **Excel Options** ([Alt]+F, T) then Proofing and click [AutoCorrect options]. Go to the **AutoFormat As You Type** tab of the AutoCorrect dialog and check the option for **Automatically as you work ► Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns**.

Comment: What if you insert all the values and then define the table *afterwards*? Is that possible?

Comment: @AndréNeves - Unfortunately no, because there is no "afterwards". The table is a workbench in constant use.

Comment: @Jeeped - That did it. Of course, I already did my workaround which is working as expected (there's only 1 row per table, no other cells in the column to autofill). 2 questions. 1st: Which setting is the latest default? I'm certain I've never checked that box before on either computer. Which should I work with? 2nd: I'm new to posting here, how do I acknowledge your comment as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I turn it off whenever I can remember where it is. Just overhead and I can Ctrl+D with the best of them when I **want** to fill down. I believe it was always turned on by default; Microsoft has always heavily proselytized the use of structured tables and arved about the 'features'. I fleshed out a response to some extent below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Excel Options** ([Alt]+F, T) then **Proofing** and click <kbd>AutoCorrect options</kbd>. Go to the **AutoFormat As You Type** tab of the AutoCorrect dialog and check/uncheck the option for **Automatically as you work** ► **Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns**.

[image: AutoCorrect]
                                          <sup>Culprit</sup>